Goals for getting into top Mathematics PhD from a Master's
My situation is fairly rare from what I can gather (at least in the U.S), so I just wanted to see if I could get some input from people who know much more than I do. I just finished my Bachelor's in Pure Mathematics, but will first be completing a Master's in math before moving onto my PhD. I had several reasons for this, with the main one being that I ultimately want to end up at the most competitive PhD program I can achieve.
My undergrad experience had many unexpected road bumps (including COVID and breaking my leg) which prevented me from doing as well as I wanted to, so my application coming out of undergrad was not extremely competitive. I took all of the honors courses offered as well as several graduate courses and did alright (about 3.7 GPA), but besides that no research or other notable efforts.
That being said, I somehow got into a top 20 math school for my Master's, so I feel like I am in a good position to potentially move up the rankings for a PhD. There have been many questions on this site asking about how to get into a top PhD program as an undergrad, but what should I be focusing on as a Master's student to achieve my goal? Since I will be in a position of higher expectations than an undergrad, my guess is I will have to focus essentially entirely on research and classes. I was just wondering if anyone had any advice for my position, or things I can be proactive in working towards when I start this fall.

Having some background in the area of your potential supervisor is probably the best thing. If you identify a supervisor and topic now, then spend some time learning and preparing, it will help your application. Even publish a good article on the topic, this will be even better.
Apart from that, just get the best marks possible on all courses.
Its not really like undergrad where entry exams etc entirely determine success, its more about getting someone's interest early and being able to justify funding. Getting amazing marks won't magic away the problem of not knowing what to study. I'd much rather take a good person who shows interest in what I do, than a disinterested, unprepared person who got the best marks at Harvard or something. Prove your interest by getting a paper accepted in the area of your potential PhD area (e.g. random graphs). Though I admit this is ultimately beyond many applicants, but it's a great start.
